# Returning char* in C calling x86 function

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I want to write a function in x86 which will be called from C program.
The function should look like this:

`char *encode(char c[], int key);`

I want it to encode a character pair (every 2 letters) from string str ("Hello World!") and write the result on a file "encode.txt". Here's my assembly code:

```
section .text
    global encode
encode:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]  ;2 bytes character pair (every 2 letters)
    mov cl, [ebp + 12]  ;the number of rotate bits (key)
    ror ax, cl      ;rotate pair (16 bits) with key
    leave
    ret
```

The problem is that when I'm calling this function from main() in C I get Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is what my C file looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern  char* encode(char cArr[], int key);
int main()
{
    FILE *fptr_save;
    fptr_save = fopen("encode.txt", "w+");

    char str[13]="Hello World!";
    int key[6] = {1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5};
    int iKey = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(str); i+=2)
        {
            char n[3] ="";
            strncat(n, &str[i], 2);
            fputs(encode(n, key[iKey]), fptr_save);
            iKey++;
        }
    fclose(fptr_save);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're rotating the low 2 bytes of the pointer value, not the pointed-to memory.  You're not accessing the memory pointed-to by EAX after you load the pointer arg.  e.g. `rol word [ax], cl`, although beware that could introduce an early `'\0'` character into your string if one char had enough low bits cleared, e.g. ASCII 64 `'@'`, and the other has enough high bits clear, e.g. ASCII 0x20 `' '`, and the right shift count.

Comment: When I used `ror al, cl` and called `extern char encode(char c, int key)`, to encode a single character. I didn't use `strncat(n, &str[i], 1)` in this case and wrote the result onto the file with `fputc(encode(str[i], key[iKey]), fptr_save)`, it already worked perfectly. I can't understand why my code above doesn't work with char* function to encode 2-pair-character.

Comment: Passing a `char*` instead of a `char` requires an extra level of indirection, just like it would in C.  Say you wanted to increment the first char of a string to the next character in the alphabet: you'd do `++ *p` (Ignoring wrap-around) and `return p`, not `return p+1`.

Comment: Your way would work if you passed a pair of characters packed into an `unsigned short`.

Comment: Write a C function doing the same. Compile it and look at the generated code. Then compare with your own code.